# Align footer to bottom in material ui cards (example inside)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I took the cards example from the material-ui side and want to arrange multiple cards in a grid. All having equal height (this I achieved using height:100%) and having the footer at the bottom of the card. Here I unsuccessfully tried to use a flex column layout. Still depending on the length of the text in the card the footer appears not at the bottom.

I prepared the problem in the following code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-xijum?file=/index.js

Could someone please give me a hint how I could manage to display the footer at the bottom of each card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your card element add `display:flex` and `flexDirection: column`. This will set all content inside `card` in one column.

```
 <Card className={classes.root} style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
```

Now `marginTop: auto` to CardContent. This will add auto margin on top.

```
<CardContent style={{ marginTop: "auto" }}>
```

Working demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-p23d0

Comment: Perfect thank you very much! I really missed that part with marginTop: auto.